# What is the alpha parameter of YCSB zipf distribution

Tags: java, ycsb, bigdata, database

YCSB comes with a ZipfianGenerator class, what is the alpha of this zipfian distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By checking the [ZipfianGenerator code in the repository](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/blob/0a330744c5b6f3b1a49e8988ccf1f6ac748340f5/core/src/main/java/com/yahoo/ycsb/generator/ZipfianGenerator.java), the default value for alpha is `1/(1-theta)` (line [142](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/blob/0a330744c5b6f3b1a49e8988ccf1f6ac748340f5/core/src/main/java/com/yahoo/ycsb/generator/ZipfianGenerator.java#L142)).

Theta is the 'zipfian constant' (line [137](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/blob/0a330744c5b6f3b1a49e8988ccf1f6ac748340f5/core/src/main/java/com/yahoo/ycsb/generator/ZipfianGenerator.java#L137)). Its default value is `0.99` (line [42](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/blob/0a330744c5b6f3b1a49e8988ccf1f6ac748340f5/core/src/main/java/com/yahoo/ycsb/generator/ZipfianGenerator.java#L42)), which gives an alpha value of `100`.

You can specify a different theta in the constructor to get a different alpha value.